# Pre-specify Bluetooth pairing request pass code in CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm creating an iBeacon maintenance app for a client.

When the app connects to the beacon, it shows a CoreBluetooth pairing request dialog:

[image: Bluetooth Pairing Request]

Because I want to make it as simple as possible for the client, and because I store the required codes on my server which the app can fetch, I'd rather specify, programmatically, what code CoreBluetooth should connect with, rather than asking the user for it.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: No, the app cannot supply the pairing code

Comment: @Robert, did you ever find a way to make this work?

Comment: @AlexI Unfortunately no, I resorted to just putting the passcode in the navigation bar to make it as easy for the user as possible.